# How to show Matrix{RGB} on Cairo surface?

Tags: julia, cairo

Cairo provides `read_from_png`, but returns value of a special type `CairoSurfaceBase`, which is hard to operate, so I choose `Matrix{RGB}`(the thing ImageIO returns).
Cairo does provide something called `set_matrix`, but the second argument must be of type `CairoMatrix`. There aren't any documents on this, so I can't figure out a way to convert between `CairoMatrix` and `Matrix{RGB}`. Or, more importantly, I want to show the `Matrix{RGB}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. convert the `Matrix{RGB}` to `Matrix{T} T<:Union{ColorTypes.ARGB32, ColorTypes.RGB24}`
2. use `CairoImageSurface` to convert it to CairoSurface
3. use `set_source_surface` to put the surface